# making code igniter registration form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

So I am making a form for people to register but its not working, and for some reason my debugger in netbeans is not working so I cannot check properly.

This is the html form

```
<?php

        if(validation_errors() != false) 
        { 
            echo '<div class="form-group alert alert-danger alert-box has-error">';
                echo'<ul>';
                    echo validation_errors('<li class="control-label">', '</li>');
                echo'</ul>';
            echo '</div>';   
        }

        /* form-horizontal */

       echo form_open('main/insertInformation'); 

        ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password_confirm" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I try to get all this information to my controller like this

```
public function insertInformation(){
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', 'Password Confirm', 'required|matches[password]');


                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('header_view');
                $this->load->view('login_view');
                $this->load->view('footer_view');
                }else{

                    $data =  array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')

                );
                    $this->db->trans_begin();
                $this->load->model('main_page');
                $this->main_page->storeRegisterInfo($data);

                $message['account_created'] = 'Your account has been created';
                $this->load->view('admin_view', $message);
                }
             }
```

And here is the model ,

```
public function storeRegisterInfo($data){
            $insert = $this->db->insert('new_users',$data);
            return $insert;

        }
```

and my database looks like this
[image]

I am pretty new to codeigniter so I am pretty sure there is alot of errors here, so please do help me out and please do explain me in steps for a better understanding. Thanks!

THis is the error
[image]

Comment: Sidenote: I see `varchar(20)` for your password column and this tells me that you're not using a safe enough password hashing function or if one's used at all. If this site is live or intended to go live, you shouldn't.  Now, have you used CI's error reporting? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html and are you checking for errors against your query?

Comment: Not working???? What not working plz add errors

Comment: @devpro If no response from OP in the next 5-10 mins. then they're either checking now, or expecting a *magic answer*. The latter won't happen; not from *moi*. ;-)

Comment: @fred-ii let's wait together for 10 min have a cup of tea :)

Comment: @devpro I'll have a cappuccino myself. I'd of opted for an espresso but that would go too quickly. Maybe a double shot would work though.

Comment: @devpro I put the error as a screenshot

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am just playing around and trying to learn :) wont go live

Comment: So what's your line 52? It's undefined.

Comment: U didn't load the model main_page

Comment: @JoeS its $this->main_page->storeRegisterInfo($data);

Comment: What is your model name??

Comment: @devpro added it now, did not work

Comment: @devpro wrote it like this now 
$this->db->trans_begin();
                    $this->load->model(main_page);
                    $this->main_page->storeRegisterInfo($data);

Comment: quotes around "main_page"

Comment: $this->load->model('main_page');  like that

Comment: @devpro alright made that, but now it works, with no errors, but nothing gets saved in the database...

Comment: happy debugging then

Comment: At least solve the problem now choking other issue

Comment: Now on database errors goto config/database.php file and true DEBUG index

Comment: @devpro is there any other way of inserting from data direclty since, nothing is being added.. or is it because i have a orig_id column, but not in the form

Comment: Well no need u can debug my friend .. Chk your HTML u didn't have the closing tag of your form

Comment: @devpro my netbeans debugger doesnt work, hence cant figure it out.... yea i saw that but that wouldnt affect..

Comment: Print_r($this->input->post); chk the values also add orig_id in data array for testing. Its not null no default field in db

Comment: i deleted orig_id still doesnt work. and where do I write the Print_r?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102177/discussion-between-devpro-and-masnad-nihit).

Comment: Ahan I checked the accepted answer good point and I told u in last comment chk my chat

Comment: @devpro sorry I had to leave urgently, but then when I saw stack , removing that part just worked, i couldnt see what you wrote in you chat, at the end, sorry!!

Comment: @MasnadNihit: not an issue friend, see my UPDATE 1... u will get the idea whats happening.

Comment: @devpro hey , since you helped me alot i hope you dont mind me asking but is there any way I can make sure that there is no same users in the database trying to register ? I watched some tutorials but couldnt get the right one..

Comment: @masnad-nihit for this plz post another question. Otherwise u checked select count(*) from table where username = 'somename' if count exist means user exist

Comment: @devpro  i made a new question, would like your help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138656/cannot-get-flash-data-to-work-to-a-page-after-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part, all should work then

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
```

Comment: And I told him in last comment to remove this read our chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102177/discussion-between-devpro-and-masnad-nihit

Answer (score 3):

After long discussion for specific for this error only you missed to load the model you need to load your model as:

```
$this->load->model('main_page');
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Removal of `$this->db->trans_begin();` solved your problem but i think its not a complete solution.

If you want to use Transactions than make sure you can only apply this for `InnoDB` or `BDB` table types not for `MyISAM`.

If you are using InnoDB and want to use t`rans_begin()` than make sure after execution of all queries you need to use `trans_commit()` otherwise this will not display anything in your database.

**[From the User Guide:](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html?highlight=trans_begin)**

```
$this->db->trans_begin(); // transaction start

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
   $this->db->trans_rollback(); // rollback if failure
}
else
{
   $this->db->trans_commit(); // commit if success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we write an model file, we have *set of conditions*. One of that is **model file should contain word of `_model`**. (Ex: `user_model`, `registration_model`)

So your model should also be changed. Now your model looks like `main_page` change it, (ex: `main_model`, `page_model`).

---

**File name** should be `Main_model.php`

**Inside your model**

```
class Main_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }

}
```

[This is how Codeigniter use the Model.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html)

Comment: The doc actually didn't say it needs to be *_model.

Comment: Yes u r right but its work without changing it.