# Cannot get flash data to work to a page after register

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, flash-message

So I am trying to get from login screen to admin screen, and I set flash data so I can tell the users if they are logged in, and also check if there is more than one user or a wrong password it will show sorry you are not logged in.
So this is my controller.

```
public function insertInformation(){
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_check_if_email_exists');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', 'Password Confirm', 'required|matches[password]');


                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('header_view');
                $this->load->view('login_view');
                $this->load->view('footer_view');
                }else{

                    $data =  array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')

                );


                    $this->load->model('main_page');
                  $user_id = $this->main_page->storeRegisterInfo($data);

                    if($user_id){
                        $user_data = array(
                            'user_id' =>$user_id,
                            'name'=> $name,
                            'logged_in' => true
                        );

                        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_sucess','you are now loggedin');
                        $this->Admin();
                    }else{
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed','you are not loggedin');
                        $this->login();
                    }

                }




        }
```

This is the modal where the data is being inserted and I am not sure how to check if the user id exist and as well as check if the user has valid info to login.

```
public function storeRegisterInfo($data){

            $insert = $this->db->insert('new_users',$data);
            $result = $this->db->get('new_users');
            if($result ->num_rows()== 1){
                return $result->row(0)->id;
            }else{
                return false;
            }


        }
```

And lastly for the view in login function its like this. Basically this is a register form but i wrote login everywhere by mistake so please dont get confused.

```
<p class="bg-danger">

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')): ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('login_failed'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>


</p>
```

And similarly for the admin.

```
<p class="bg-success">

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('login_success')): ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('login_success'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>


</p>


<h1>hello</h1>
```

So I cannot get the flash data to work ,and as well as cant identify if the user already exists or wrote the wrong password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting flash data redirect the page

```
redirect('controllerNmae/Method');
```

---

**EDIT 01**

**In view**

```
<?php
    if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('login_sucess')))
    {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('login_sucess');
    }

    if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')))
    {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('login_failed');
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('login_sucess')))
    {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('<?php $this->session->flashdata('login_sucess'); ?>');
        </script>
    <?
    }

     if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('login_failed')))
    {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('<?php $this->session->flashdata('login_failed'); ?>');
        </script>
    <?
    }
?>
```

> **Tip:** Use this library [alertify JS](http://alertifyjs.com/). Its gives nice user experience
> Ex
>
> ```
> <script>
>    alertify.success('<?php $this->session->flashdata('login_sucess'); ?>');
> </script>
> ```

Comment: i did it, but it did not go to the admin page..
$this->session->set_flashdata('login_sucess','you are now loggedin');
                        redirect('main/Admin');

Comment: main is controller ??

Comment: Method name is Admin ??

Comment: yeaa, public function Admin(){
                $this->load->view('header_view');
                $this->load->view('admin_view');
                $this->load->view('footer_view');
        }

Comment: Is controller redirect the page ??

Comment: i did not understand, what did you mean ?

Comment: now your controller redirect you to page or still in same view ??

Comment: yea I go to the admin page, but the flash data doesnt show.

Comment: <p style='margin-top: 200px;' class="bg-success">
    
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('login_success')): ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('login_success'); ?>
    
<?php endif; ?>
    
    
</p>


<h1>hello</h1>

Comment: @MasnadNihit any response ??

Comment: dint work :( , so I just did the normal php way 
$message['account_created'] = 'Your account has been created' ;
                    $this->load->view('header_view');
                    $this->load->view('admin_view',$message);
                    $this->load->view('footer_view');
dunno whats wrong , seems to me like ur code is perfect.

Comment: @MasnadNihit Im 100% sure. Cz im using it. Did you load session library ??

Comment: @Abdulla yes ofcourse, i loaded it like this
public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('javascript');
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->library('email');
  $this->load->library('session');
}

Comment: So this work fine. I think you are missing some thing. Did you add html part in your all the view ??

Comment: Add that before `</head>` in your page

Comment: and before loading session library add this too `ob_start();`

Comment: @Abdulla tried it, didnt work, dont know what I am missing, and also I tried this
$message['account_created'] = 'Your account has been created' ;
                    redirect('main/Admin', $message); 
did not work, I think something is wrong with the redirect

Comment: in redirect you cant use Bind variable. **load session library in `autoload.php` as well and try once**

Comment: Thanks for all the info, I will try more and see what mistake I am doing, but your answer is perfect :) there is something wrong with my codeigniter for sure, and I am still learning how to do all this, maybe I made a mistake somewhere, but I will accept ur answer since I know that its right :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MasnadNihit Thax. If any question post. Will help you much as i can